# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn style

Tags: wpf, styles, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I use `ComboboxColumn` in `DataGrid` which works fine.

However there is a style issue:
When cursor is not on the column, the `ComboboxColumn` looks like a `textboxColumn`. Once I click it, a tiny arrow on the right corner displays so it looks like a combobox.

I want it to display like a combobox even when it is not clicked or focused. I feel it is `ElementStyle`, but not sure what to change to exactly. Does someone know how to do this?

```xml
xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 

                    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" x:Name="column" Header="Column" 
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=RelParams.ColumnName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel= High}"
    DisplayMemberPath="cName"
    SelectedValuePath="cName">

    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelInfo.Columns}" />
        </Style>
    </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelInfo.Columns}" />
        </Style>
    </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>

</dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx)).

Example:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyColumn">
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Another question. The datagridrow has alternation background.     <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1" ><Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" /></Trigger>. I want the combobox in the datagridrow to use the same background as the textbox in the datagridrow, also when the datagridrow is selected, the combobox should be highlighted in the same color as the rest of the row.  How to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: @toosensitive if it's another question you should create new question. Comment isn't the best way to do this :)