# DataGridComboBox Entries through Converter

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

Quick WPF Question.
Here's my situation:
I have a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with an `Enum` as `ItemsSource`. 
But of course I don't want to actually Displays the Enum Values.
I have a converter which looks up the according strings in a Dictionary according to the 'Enum Item'. That's all good and fancy. But where do I have to declare the converter?

I tried this:

```
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="120" Header="Expense.Column.FoodCode" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource FoodCodes}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding FoodCode, Converter={StaticResource FoodCodeConverter}}" />
```

But `SelectedItemBinding` is apparently the wrong place.
Which Property of `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is responsible for the displayed item text?

Thanx in advance.

EDIT:
So far I have:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="86" Header="Expense.Column.WageAccount" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding WageAccount, Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource WageAccounts}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Expenses.WaggeAccount, Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` also doesn't call the Converter btw.

Comment: Have you tried ItemsSource?

Comment: If I'm honest I would do this using template and style, handle these things by your self and have full control over how and what you display. unless you don't want to then ignore me :-)

Comment: I've been already told to use a 'Style' for that. I still have no idea which property is relevant for that. Could you post a little example? Basically I just need the XAML lines to tell WPF to actually fill the TextBlocks inside the ComboBox with the values from the Converter. As you can see, WPF is still confusing as hell to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Finally I got it!

```
                    <fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="86" Header="Expense.Column.WageAccount" >
                    <fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WageAccount, Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource WageAccounts}">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </fpc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Its basically what I posted in the Edit of the original question with one small differenct
The Line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Expenses.WageAccount, Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
```

changed to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource WageAccountConverter}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I think this should be sufficient for you

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.aspx) this article gives you info about style for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn Style`

Here is an example of how you use it.

This example is based on this Question [WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443091/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-style)

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyColumn">
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ... />
    </DataTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

With that being said you need also the `ComboBox Style` which can be found here [MSDN - ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On top of that when you do the `ComboBoxStyle` you can use your converter then, cause display of the items is handled by `ComboBox` and not the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.
HTH :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! Gonna read all of the links, test it and then report back (or just mark as answered if I manage to get it working).

Comment: Cool TBH I think you will only need to override the `ComboBoxStyle` cause you already are using the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` and from there it's a straight road to victory !

Comment: Honestly I still don't get it. I know how to apply the style in the Template Column. But I still have no idea which property is responsible for the text entries in the `ComboBox`.